# Load test with multiple credentials

Tags: performance, load-testing, visualstudio

Okay so I have created a very simple webtest. The purpose of this webtest is to attempt to login whilst simulating a few failing attempts.

The webtest has the obvious credentials associated with it:-

Username
Password
What I want to be able to do is when I associate the web test with a load test I want to be able to login with 25 users using multiple different credentials, how can I set these and then tell the test to use the multiple credentials?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could use a plugin, although there is a simpler way.  You can create a CSV file with the list of usernames and passwords you want to iterate through and then create a datasource.  When you execute the web test, it will iterate through all of the items in the CSV file, one line for each test execution.

Based on what you outlined above I would probably create 2 tests and 2 CSV files.  One test would be a test where the login is successful and it would have a list of valid usernames and passwords and the second test would be for invalid logins.

An alternative would be to have a single test and in the CSV have 3 columns, user name|password|expectedResponse.  You could then create a validation rule that looks for the value in the expectedResponse column and passes so long as it matches.  A single test would work fine, but the reporting would probably be cleaner with two test cases.

Answer (score 3):

web test Plugins was my solution I can write some code to iterate or go through a data set quite easily. Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting;

namespace SampleRequestPlugins
{
    public class DynamicUsername : WebTestPlugin
    {
        static int _testIterationNumber = 1;

        public override void PostWebTest(object sender, PostWebTestEventArgs e)
        {
            e.WebTest.Context["TestIterationNumber"] = _testIterationNumber;
            _testIterationNumber++;
        }

        public override void PreWebTest(object sender, PreWebTestEventArgs e)
        {
            e.WebTest.Context["username"] = "username" + _testIterationNumber.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I created a new class library with the above class. I then referenced the class library project in my test project, I could then right click on the top node of a web test and add as a web test plugin.

Answer (score 2):

I also suggest reading these great MSDN docs:

[Binding a Data Source to a Web Performance Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404707%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[How to: Set Credentials on a Web Performance Test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182548%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> You can set the credentials for any Web site that uses basic
>   authentication or Integrated Windows authentication. Web sites that
>   contain personal information often require user authentication before
>   displaying any information through the browser. By setting the
>   credentials for a Web performance test, you can conduct tests on sites
>   that require this level of authentication. You set credentials in Web
>   performance tests in the Web Performance Test Editor. For more
>   information about how to edit a Web performance test, see How to: Edit
>   an Existing Web Performance Test Using the Web Performance Test
>   Editor.